# is there a way to view the source of a module from within the python console?

Tags: python

if I'm in the python console and I want to see how a particular module works, is there an easy way to dump the source?

Comment: the question was wheteher or not there was an easy way to do it from within the console. The inspect module is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Voting to re-open because the question linked as a duplicate asks about a function rather than a module. The answer is the same, but someone searching for this question would not necessarily ask the other question.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate. It asks about features of the Python console and not for code inspection. Therefore Michał Marczyk is answering it correctly for the IPython console.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Some of the methods of [inspect](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) module are well-suited for this purpose:

```
import module
import inspect
src = inspect.getsource(module)
```

Comment: sometimes doesn't work. for example: see this screenshot: https://recolic.net/tmp/snap-0508-203529.png

Comment: @recolic link has expired

Comment: @LuisFelipe I have lost the screenshot... Sorry for that and just ignore my comment plz.

Comment: Does not work for "built-in" modules.

Answer (score 9):

Using IPython, you can do this:

```
In [1]: import pyparsing
In [2]: pyparsing.Word??
```

...and the source will be displayed, if possible. I guess this must use `inspect` under the hood, but the added convenience of ? / ?? is fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try

```
print(open('mymodule.py').read())
```

?

See [`file.read()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.read).

Comment: this dumps the content of any file.

Comment: for this to work you would have to be in the directory where the module is placed. Sorta defeats the purpose in my opinion.

Comment: You can use `__file__` instead of the static string.

Comment: `__file__` does not work for "built-in" modules