# How to retrieve code from loaded python module

Tags: python, ipython, spyder

I am new here, so sorry for any mistakes. I am using spyder 3.0.0 and iPython console.

I have mistakenly overwritten my custom module file. My last hope is that I have loaded it in iPython console. Is there any way to get the source code "back" from the console?
The console lists all the names (of my overwritten module) after calling `dir (modulename)`, it also creates objects and hint arguments for objects' methods.
I have tried (after importing inspect) `print(inspect.getsource(MyClass))`, but it throws

```
File "C:\Users\witek\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 613, in getfile
raise TypeError('{!r} is a built-in class'.format(object))

TypeError: <module '__main__'> is a built-in class
```

If I call `print(inspect.getsource(MyModule))` it returns the source code of the file that I saved under my module name.

I will really appreciate any help! :)

Comment: is this what youre looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055110/is-there-a-way-to-view-the-source-of-a-module-from-within-the-python-console

Comment: You’re looking for a decompiler that you can apply to the _code objects_ in your surviving session.

Comment: what if you use `inspect.getsource` on a function inside the module?

Comment: @Stanley thanks, but solutions posted there didn't work for my case (source code file gone)

Comment: @xdze2
 `File "C:\Users\witek\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 804, in findsource
    if pat.match(lines[lnum]): break

IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @DavisHerring and that's what I did, just in time, thank you! Luckily .pyc file survived and i used uncompyle6 getting it all back. What a relief!! :) I wonder what if I couldn't find .pyc file in __pycache__ , would compileall.compile_dir work in that case...

Comment: @WitekJaworski: You can’t compile files that aren’t there, but it is possible (if more difficult) to decompile the _loaded_ bytecode in memory.