# module 'tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers' has no attribute 'SGD'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am working with python 3.9, tensorflow 2.7.0 with a modified version of Mask RCNN https://github.com/leekunhee/Mask_RCNN/blob/tensorflow2.0/mrcnn). I am working with tensorflow .keras and specifically import

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python import keras 
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.python.keras import layers as KL
from tensorflow.python.keras import utils as KU
from tensorflow.python.eager import context
from tensorflow.python.keras import initializers as KI#nuevo
from tensorflow.python.keras import engine as KE
from tensorflow.python.keras import models as KM
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
```

I call this module in this code

```
`optimizer = SGD(lr=learning_rate, momentum=momentum, clipnorm=self.config.GRADIENT_CLIP_NORM)`
```

and get this error

```
~/work/model.py in compile(self, learning_rate, momentum)
   2234         """
   2235 
-> 2236         # Optimizer object
   2237         optimizer = SGD(
   2238             lr=learning_rate, momentum=momentum,
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers' has no attribute 'SGD'
```

I have tried calling `tensforflow.keras.optimizers.SGD` or `tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers.SGD`
instead but nothing seems to work.

I am working on a jupyter notebook in IBM Watson Studio

Thanks!

Comment: I would follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2055165/3765034 - for how to look for the source code to see what is there. if installed correctly you should have it there. I would say that repo you are forking is requiring >= 2.2 tf so things could have changed from then to 2.9

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and came across your post.  I'm running python v3.9.7  on a MacBook Pro with an M1 processor.  (I'm not quite sure how to check my tensor flow version, as I'm still learning).

To better understand what was happening, I ran specifically:

> from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import SGD

did not work.

However, it *did* work when I ran:

> from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD

from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD

It seems as if the tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers has different optimisers than tensorflow.keras.optimizers.  However, I can't find any documentation on this and am surprised as something as fundamental as stochastic gradient descent (SGD) would be missing?